# Is $\le$ defined by $\langle _1, _1 \rangle \le \langle _2, _2 \rangle$, if $_1 \le _2 \land_1 \ge _2$ a linear order?

Tags: relations, order-theory

I need to tell if the relation $\le$ defined by relationship $\langle _1, _1 \rangle \le \langle _2, _2 \rangle$, if $_1 \le _2$ $\land$ $_1 \ge _2$ linear order?

I have already proven that the relation is an order, but I need to decide if it is a linear order and why. Thanks for any help!

Comment: In what set are $x1, y1, x2, y2$ elements?  One can only define a linear order on a specified set.

Answer (score 2):

A linear order needs two elements to be comparable i.e. for $\left<x_1,y_1\right>,\left<x_2,y_2\right>$
we have either
$$\left<x_1,y_1\right>\preceq\left<x_2,y_2\right>$$
or $$\left<x_2,y_2\right>\preceq\left<x_1,y_1\right>.$$
If you can find two pairs where neither is the case, you have proven that the relation can't be a linear order.

Comment: so ⟨1, 2⟩ ⪯ ⟨2, 1⟩ and ⟨2, 1⟩ ⪰ ⟨1, 2⟩?

Comment: that's the same thing.

Comment: can you help me find any pairs?

Comment: try $<1,1>$ and $<2,2>$

Comment: but ⟨1, 2⟩ ⪯ ⟨2, 1⟩ is true, right?

Comment: yes it certainly is.